# EJB remote calls after 60 seconds lead to a rollbackOnly

Tags: transactions, ejb, websphere

I have an application which runs in an IBM WebSphere Application Server 8 and has an EJB 3.0 Stateless Bean. This bean calls a Service which consists of an EJB 2 Stateless Bean. The second bean is called in a for loop. This means is called at least 300 times. The process takes place in a transaction.
The first bean is marked as such:

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
```

The second bean:

```
<session-type>Stateless</session-type>
<transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
```

Sometimes the entire transaction takes more than 60 seconds. For this reason I set the transaction timeouts to 600 seconds:

```
totalTranLifetimeTimeout="600" 
LPSHeuristicCompletion="ROLLBACK" 
propogatedOrBMTTranLifetimeTimeout="600"
```

But I still encounter a problem for which I didn't find the cause and a solution.
After 60 seconds from the first call the service (Method B) sets for the transaction the attribute rolebackonly on true. The methods runs till the end but there is nothing saved in the database because of this - everything is rolled back.

I could not find a solution to get more information about the component which sets it to true (the container or the database) and for which reason.

I hope I explained everything right and any idea or solution will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Application Component Transaction Timeout set, it would override the global timeout values, as shown in tables 1, 2 on [this knowledge center page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/udat_contranserv.html).
Here is another [knowledge center page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tjta_entra2.html) that describes how to configure the Component Transaction Timeout. Check if it is set to 60, and if so, increase the value.

Also, just noticed you mentioned it was a remote EJB call, so you should also look at the value of the Client Inactivity Timeout, which has a default value of 60 seconds and "Specifies the maximum duration, in seconds, between transactional requests from a remote client. Any period of client inactivity that exceeds this timeout results in the transaction being rolled back in this application server." per the knowledge center doc from the first link.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
There is no "Application Component Transaction Timeout" set either in deployment descriptors or on the server.
On the other hand, the "Client Inactivity Timeout" doesn't make any sense. But even so I changed the value on both servers to 120 seconds without any positive result.
As I said in my first post the remote ejb is called in a for loop and in the first call after 60 seconds from the very first call the flag was already set to true. I see this because at the beginning and the end of the remote call I log the value of SessionContext.getRollbackOnly().